# Cannot apply for new position after the job offer got expired

Tags: job-offer

A year ago I got an offer from TCS and due to some unforeseen circumstances I couldn't either accept or reject the offer and the offer got expired. One year later now I am trying to apply for a new position at TCS through iBegin portal, but all I get is an error saying 'You can't apply for this position as your profile is considered for an opening'. I am also not able to make any edits in the profile. In this case how can I proceed to apply for the post ?

Comment: VTC - You need to contact the company, not us - only they can sort that out.

Answer (score 6):

> In this case how can I proceed to apply for the post ?

Pick up the phone, call the company, ask to speak to someone in the hiring department and then explain your dilemma.  They should be able to work with you to resolve the issue and allow you to apply.  If they can't ( or won't ), then consider that a red flag for this company.

Comment: Of course the company may well regard the '(n)either accept (n)or reject' an offer as a red flag on their end.